# What changes should be made to a web application from MySQL to MariaDB?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, mariadb

I have a web application developed with Java (JSP, Servlets, etc) where I use MySQL as DBMS, take care:

- Connection Pool
- PreparedStatement
- Stored Procedures
  -Triggers

My question is how many changes I have to make my application (In addition to changing the name of the driver and the. Jar) for smooth functions with MariaDB.?

Or what considerations should I take for that change?

Comment: I thank all your answers, what happens is that linux distribution changes to Fedora 19 and just saw that replaced MySQL for MariaDB

Comment: Yes, and I think it is a good step in order to keep Fedora purely open source:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [compability list](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) on MariaDBs pages so you can see that 99% is the same like in MySQL. And from Java perspective, your statements and connection pool should remain the same, however I suppose they can be minor changes in a way how to write stored procedures.

So generally, this transition shouldn't cause any problems but you still want to test this thoroughly in order to be sure that nothing really changed.

Comment: It's 2018 and this is becoming less and less true. Aside from Mariadb 10.1, 10.2 and 10.3 all requiring incremental updates, MariaDB is a lot pickier when it comes to things like constraint names across tablesor using NOW() as a default in dates (which wasn't allowed until 10.3)

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is a direct fork of the MySQL codebase which hasn't diverged much from it yet. The developers are doing their best to avoid any compatibility-breaking changes to make sure that MariaDB can be used as a drop-in replacement for MySQL. That means switching from MySQL to MariaDB is comparable with updating your MySQL version.

It is unlikely that you will have to make any modifications at your application at all. Still, a proper integration test is definitely in order before migrating the production system, especially when your MySQL version isn't up-to-date.